# How turn off/on typer phase in scala repl and sbt console

Tags: scala, console, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to switch phase without exiting from current session? I've tried entering :power mode, but it still doesn't print types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SBT just add the following setting:

```
set scalacOptions in (Compile, console) := "-Xprint:typer"
```

in REPL you can use `:settings -Xprint:typer`

Comment: In what version of Scala does the REPL provide a `:settings` command? In 2.10.3 I get "settings: no such command.  Type :help for help." when I use your example `:settings -Xprint:typer`. I tried "power mode," as well, with the same result.

Comment: @RandallSchulz i have a version 2.11-RC1, so it is available only since 2.11

Comment: 2.11.X is ok..But in sbt 0.13,you should use `set scalacOption in (Compile, console) := Seq("-Xprint:typer")`

Comment: @fairjm You missed an 's'.  Complete command: `set scalacOptions in (Compile, console) := Seq("-Xprint:typer")`

Comment: Or use `+=` and no `Seq`

Comment: @nafg if `scalacOptions` is not an empty Seq, then `+=` might not be the desired / expected behaviour

Comment: Sometimes, we have to use `set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-Xprint:namer", "-Xprint:typer")`